# google maps application from my application wid a label over the location

Tags: android, google-maps

I can open google maps from my application and have a pointer over the location i am pointing to.

Instead i wanted to open google maps application from my application---- as is when user clicks on an address google maps application opens up with that particular point.

for that i used

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse("geo:lat,lng?q=lat,lng")));
```

Here lat=34.456373 and lng=-45.464748

Google maps application is opening but that particular location is not coming up instead my present location is coming up.How to rectify that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 String geoCode = "geo:0,0?q=" + PLACE_LATITUDE + ","+ PLACE_LONGITUDE + "(" + PLACE_NAME + ")";
 Intent sendLocationToMap = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
 Uri.parse(geoCode));
 startActivity(sendLocationToMap);
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html refer for more detail..

Comment: What if we dont give the place name?

Comment: if u enter place name give exact result of your otherwise all place they saw you of exact latitude and longitude..its simple bro..

Comment: ya  i got that thanx......just one last thing..... on that particular location can we show our own default text?

Answer (score 0):

```
    String uri = String.format("geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
lat.setText(String.valueOf(latitude));
                        lon.setText(String.valueOf(longitude));
                        String showMap = String.valueOf(latitude) + ","
                                + String.valueOf(longitude);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + (showMap)));
                        try {
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in gps "+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
```